# Do not want to install custom modules during Magento 2 installation

Tags: magento2, installation

I've a project which contains `magento 2` core files and a few custom modules. Now I'm trying to install Magento.

During magento installation I see all custom modules are getting installed.

I don't want these modules to be installed during Magento installation.

Later based on necessity I want to install those modules.

How to achieve it?

Comment: How you are Installing the Magento 2 Instance via command line or browser?

Comment: @KeyurShah Bhai I think he is installing from browser

Comment: in that case your answer seems good option as of now nothing interesting in mind :) @MurtuzaZabuawala

Comment: @KeyurShah I gotta hint from  my answer's comment from him

Comment: Yes, I'm installing it from browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to follow @Divyesh steps

Then you can do following

at the time of installation

**in step 4(Step 4: Customize Your Store)**

Click on **Advanced module configuration**

and un-select modules that you don't want to install

**Update as per OP's requirement**

Go to `app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php` file

and comment below code

```
$pathList[] = dirname(__DIR__) . '/code/*/*/registration.php';
```

your `app/code` module will not autometically load

but after this if you want to install your `app/code` module then you have to uncomment this line

Comment: Thats helpful. Though this repo is going to be used my multiple developers and generally we don't expand Advanced tab and unselect modules during magento installation. Is it possible to achieve it by modifying some code to avoid manual unselection?

Comment: @amitshree in that case you can create that `config.php` file with status 0

Comment: This repo will be used across multiple projects and based on project different custom modules will be used (so different config.php file).  I was looking for a solution if it's possible to control it on code level mentioning dependency. Is that possible or I've to manually update config.php for each project?

Comment: @amitshree check updated answer

Comment: Commenting above code says `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property: Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInitd46d13460d2a5fdbbb6dd611a4663152::$fallbackDirsPsr0`

Comment: @amitshree just comment this line `0 => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/app/code'`

Comment: Done that. Custom modules are still showing selected in advanced modules configuration section. Should I continue install?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77191/discussion-between-murtuza-zabuawala-and-amitshree).

Answer (score 3):

- If your source code has `app/etc/config.php` file available then just disable modules which you don't want to include in installation.

For EX:

```
 'Package_CustomModule' => 1,
```

**Replace with**

```
 'Package_CustomModule' => 0,
```

**if you don't have `app/etc/config.php` Go to your custom module and remove your custom module folders**

Comment: `app/etc/config.php` is created during project install so disabling modules through this file is not possible and I want to keep these custom modules in my repo and install/enable required custom  modules after magento is installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to install custom module while Magento installation, rename module `registration.php` file.

Now you can install Magento without installing the custom module.

correct module `registration.php` file when you want to install custom module.